# Determining if a number is prime in the above code

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, primality-test

I have a simple problem: take a number and determine if it is prime. I cannot figure out why on earth the following does not work.

```
def prime(x):
    for i in range (2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False 
        return True

prime(21)
```

This returns true! I have no idea why.

Comment: You need to let your loop run fully first before returning. It should be outside the for loop

Comment: because `return`means end of the function - and in your case, this will happen already at `i==2`: returning `False` if `x % 2 == 0` and `True`otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have put `return True` inside the for loop, so it only checks whether the number is divisible by two and if not, it returns true.

Rather use this

```
def prime(x):
    for i in range (2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False 
    return True
```

Also to improve efficiency a bit use 
`for i in range (2, int(x/2)+1)` since once you have reached x/2 no number after that can divide it anyhow.

In future try debugging your code by printing values of loop indexes where it defaults or using a debugger, it is real helpful and helps you improve as a programmer.